# How to correctly wait in POM using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have setup some explicit waits for various things in my tests but have had to specify strings for my XPaths, ids etc. So my page setups include things like...

```
public const string ApplyDatasetButton_XPath = "//*[@id='btn_apply_datasets']";
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = ApplyDatasetButton_XPath)]
public IWebElement ApplyDatasetButton { get; set; }
```

...and then I am using this in my test in the wait like...

```
SeleniumGetMethods.WaitForElementVisible(By.XPath(ApplyDatasetButton_XPath), 20);
```

...where the wait is setup as...

```
public static void WaitForElementVisible(By element, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DriverSetup.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(element));
        }
    }
```

However creating the string seems overkill but I couldn't figure out how to just use the element created. Basically is there a way in C# to do something like...

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@id='btn_apply_datasets']")]
public IWebElement ApplyDatasetButton { get; set; }

SeleniumGetMethods.WaitForElementVisible(ApplyDatasetButton, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

An Extension piece for ExpectedConditions like so:

```
/// <summary>
    /// An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page
    /// and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but
    /// also has a height and width that is greater than 0.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="locator">The locator used to find the element.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="T:OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement" /> once it is located and visible.</returns>
    public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementIsVisible(IWebElement element) => driver =>
    {
        try
        {
            return ElementIfVisible(element);
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    };

    private static IWebElement ElementIfVisible(IWebElement element)
    {
        if (!element.Displayed)
            return null;
        return element;
    }
```

Then extend the IWebDriver interface like so

```
public static IWebElement WaitUntilElementIsVisible(this IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element, int timeOutInSeconds = DefaultTimeoutSeconds)
    {
        try
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOutInSeconds));
            return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(element)); //Wait finishes when return is a non-null value or 'true'
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
        {
            MethodLogger.OutputLog($"Element: {element} was not found on current page.");
            MethodLogger.OutputLog(ex);
            return null;
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
        {
            MethodLogger.OutputLog($"Timed out Looking for Clickable Element; {element}: Waited for {timeOutInSeconds} seconds.");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@id='btn_apply_datasets']")]
public IWebElement ApplyDatasetButton { get; set; }
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.WaitUntilElementIsVisible(ApplyDatasetButton, 20);
```